# error: file `/boot/` not found. No such device: `/.disk/info`. No such device: `/.disk/mini-info`

Tags: boot, usb, grub

I installed grub onto my stick: `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot --recheck --removable --efi-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt -v /dev/sde`.

Then try to boot from this USB stick. Right before menu appears I see these error messages:

```
error: file `/boot/` not found. 
No such device: /.disk/info. 
No such device: /.disk/mini-info.
```

Why they appear and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution [here](https://wiki-ubuntuusers-de.translate.goog/Universal_stand-alone_grub_f%C3%BCr_BIOS_und_EFI_auf_USB_flashkey_und_internen_HDD_und_SSD/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp) (see paragraph 7 at the end of article).

> This error message appears only if you use boot directory different from `/boot` in EFI mode.

This message does not break any functionality. If you want it does not appear, then use `/mnt/boot` as `--boot-directory`:
`sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot --recheck --removable --efi-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot -v /dev/sde`